# Laravel 5.8: The items.0.id field is required. Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I am working on an application for the company I work for, this application was made using Laravel 5.8 and MySQL. I have managed to incorporate improvements and so on but there is something that I still can't solve (I'm a junior programmer and I still don't have that much experience). The issue is that there is a many-to-many relationship, I need to make it possible to link new items to the project with their respective quantities in the edit view of a project, in turn it should be possible to unlink previously related items if needed. But nevertheless when trying to do it, the view responds to me with the following error: The items.0.id field is required.The items.0.quantity field is required.

Below the code:

ProjectController:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
        $items = Item::all();
        $project_items = $project->items()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $project_items_quantity = $project->items()->pluck('quantity', 'id')->toArray();
        $item_project = ItemProject::where('project_id', $id)->get();

        return view('includes.edit_delete_project',
            compact('items', 'project_items', 'project_items_quantity', 'item_project'))
            ->with(['project'=> Project::getProjectById($id),
            'entities'=>Entity::getEntities(),
                'countries'=>Country::getCountries()]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'code' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'entity' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'country' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'items' => 'nullable|array',
            'items.*.id' => 'required|integer|exists:items,id',
            'items.*.quantity' => 'required|integer|min:0',
        ));

        $project->update($request->only(['code', 'entity', 'country']));

        if ($request->has('items')) {
            $items = $request->input('items');

            $currentItems = $project->items->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $detachItems = array_diff($currentItems, array_column($items, 'id'));
            $project->items()->detach($detachItems);

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $project->items()->syncWithoutDetaching([$item['id'] => ['quantity' => $item['quantity']]]);
            }
        }

        return response()->json($project);
    }
```

Project Model:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = "project";

    protected $fillable = ['code',
        'entity',
        'country'];
    protected $hidden = ['id'];

    public static function getProjects()
    {
        return Project::all();
    }

    public static function getProjectById($id)
    {
        return Project::find($id);
    }

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'project_item',
            'project_id', 'item_id')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

Project edit view:

```
<!-- Edit -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit{{$project->id}}">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><b><span class="employee_id">Edit Project</span></b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/includes/edit_delete_project/{{ $project->id }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="code" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span style="color: red">*</span> Code</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" type="text" class="form-control"
                                   id="code" name="code" value="{{$project->code}}" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="entity" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span style="color: red">*</span> Company</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control" id="entity" name="entity" required>
                                <option value="" selected>{{collect($entities)->where('id', $project->entity)->first()->company}}</option>
                                @foreach($entities as $entity)
                                    <option value="{{$entity->id}}">{{$entity->company}} </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="country" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span style="color: red">*</span> Country</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country" required>
                                <option value="" selected>{{collect($countries)->where('id', $project->country)->first()->iso}}</option>
                                @foreach($countries as $country)
                                    <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}} </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="items" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span style="color: red"></span> Items</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @foreach($items as $item)
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="items[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" id="item{{ $item->id }}">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="item{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->pn }} - {{ $item->detail }}</label>

                                    <input type="number"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           min="1"
                                           style="width: 100px;"
                                           id="quantity_{{$item->id}}"
                                           name="quantity_{{$item->id}}"
                                           value="{{old('quantity_' . $item->id)}}" placeholder="Quantity">
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i
                                class="fa fa-close"></i> Close
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" name="edit"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                            Update
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried various recommendations from the internet but still have not been successful with any. It is the only thing that I need of all that they asked me to finish the application.
I just need to solve what I exposed at the beginning and I will be very grateful to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Apprently there is issue with data or the format of data which is being passed. "The items.0.id field is required" message means, the object at 0th index of items array doesn't have the id property.